# How to run my C program from anywhere within the System (Ubuntu 10.10)?

Tags: shell, environment-variables

Friends,
I want to add my C program's path to the environment variable PATH. My C program called "md5". So that I can execute it from anywhere (i.e any directory).

My md5 program is located at `/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program`. So what I did was to put:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program
```

in the running shell. This only makes temporary changes and lets me run the `md5` program from anywhere temporarily.

```
root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq# md5 -sanis
MD5 ("anis") = 38a1ffb5ccad9612d3d28d99488ca94b
```

But I want to make this change permanent.

I tried to put the line `PATH=$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program` at the end of `/home/ahuq/.bashrc` and `/home/ahuq/.profile` files. I logged out of the shell and
went in again. But it didn't work:

```
root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq# md5 -sanis
No command 'md5' found, did you mean:
Command 'cd5' from package 'cd5' (universe)
Command 'mdu' from package 'mtools' (main)
Command 'mdb' from package 'mono-debugger' (universe)
md5: command not found
```

Maybe I am putting the `PATH` statement in the wrong place of the above mentioned files. There are a lot if-else-fi structures inside those two files. Do I need to put the `PATH` statement inside any of those structures? Do I just logout or do I have to restart the system to make the changes active?

Comment: It seems like your .bashrc and .profile files aren't running. If you do `source ~/.bashrc` or `source ~/.profile`, does the path get fixed?

Comment: Always use quotes: `PATH="$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program"`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're putting the path in the correct place. It might not work if you have spaces somewhere in the path however. You can try doing this for correctness:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program"
```

Alternatively, just put the app inside `/usr/local/bin`. Or even install the `md5sum` package, which seems to do the same thing as your app.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your dotfiles, it's hard to say for sure, but from what you quoted, you left out the "export" when you added it to the .profile and .bashrc files.

Comment: Nope. I tried that. Putting in: "export PATH=$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program" at the end of "/home/ahuq/.bashrc" and "/home/ahuq/.profile" files do not help.

Comment: Just to be sure - you also need to either log out and back in after adding `export` or you need to manually source the files from the command line by `source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

From your question:

> root@ahuq-kitchen:/home/ahuq# md5 -sanis

But, you say you only edited the .bashrc for your user.

If you need the new path to be global for every user, you could edit `/etc/bash.bashrc` (this could cause issues, if other users cannot execute `md5` from your homedir due to permissions issues). Or, if you only need the change to also apply to root as well as your local user, consider edited `/root/.bashrc` as well.

Alternatively and more preferred, as root, you could consider installing/copying the `md5` command to `/usr/local/bin`, which is my default in everyone's `$PATH` in Ubuntu.

You could do this with:

> $ sudo cp /home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program/md5 /usr/local/bin
>   $ sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/md5
>   $ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/md5

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are running `bash` (and not some other Bourne shell flavour such as `sh`) ? Try `ps $$` and `echo $SHELL` to verify that.

Also, you could put statements such as `echo IN FILE XYZ` directly before adding this to the path to see whether your path settings are actually executed.

And put the adding of your path as close to the end of your shell startup file as possible. I've seen startup files in the past where at some point the entire `PATH` is reset and rebuild from scratch instead of appending new directories

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced some issues with adding executables to my path.
What worked for me is adding the line `export PATH=$PATH:/home/ahuq/MappingServer/md5_program` to the `~/.bash_profile`.

Unfortunately I don't know why but for met .bashrc didn't work but .bash_profile did.